# Python xlwt - looping through sales (works with csv.writer)

Tags: python, export-to-csv, export-to-excel, xlwt

I am trying to transfer my .csv output to .xslx as well but am having a bit of a trouble understanding how to loop through my sales with xlwt. I've read the following tutorials but no help there:
https://toricode.com/python-write-excel-file-using-xlwt/ and
https://tutorialmeta.com/question/understanding-for-loop-with-xlwt

The way it's done with csv.writer is as follows:

```
fieldnames = [
        _("Date"),
        _("Type"),
        _("Price")
        _("CustomerFName"),
        _("CustomerLName"),
    ]
   
    writer = csv.writer(output)
    writer.writerow(fieldnames)

    for s in sales:
        for sale in s.sales.all():
            row = [
                s.date,
                sale.type,
                sale.price,
                s.fName,
                s.lName,
            ]
     return output
```

Any ideas or good examples I could look into?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the example you showed does not write anything out, nor does it define `output`. is the question how to write out to an `xlsx` file?

Comment: also this is an old library which has been archived per GitHub, are you aware of this?

Comment: @gold_cy thank's for your input. currently I am using the above example to output and write a csv file from the website. I am looking to write a XLSX file instead. With same output, just instead of comma separated I would like to have it in columns.

Comment: I now found this writer and will try with it. https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/tutorial01.html